# Tweetstream Daemon not working; not printing to console, not storing objects in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, couchdb, tweetstream

I'm trying to build an application where one of the core background processes is to scrape tweets. and store it inCouchDB-based Cloudant This is among the first serious Rails projects that I've pursued (I've been learning Ruby/Rails over the last few weeks) and I'm stuck, even after looking through the various issues addressed here.

What puzzles me is the fact that I can't even get a simple Daemon to store anything in the ActiveRecord model, let alone another database model (I figured it would be best to proceed incrementally like this).

I'm using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.9.3. This is what I currently have in the file raker.rb under directory script:

https://gist.github.com/arjunh/5887446

I run the command rails runner script/raker.rb start, but nothing happens seemingly; nothing is printed to the console, nore is anything stored to the database.

I'm quite sure that my OAuth details are correct (I fooled around with the Twitter gem in the rails console and everything seemed fine there).

Answer (score 0):

I have been using:

```
TweetStream::Daemon.new('tracker', :log_output => true).track("Zork") do |twt|
end
```

Then to start daemon in console I use:

```
ruby ##filname start
```

this  seems to work in the sense that I get a stream from twitter, the only problem I have is I cannot store the tweets into a database. Very frustrating.